# Elasticsearch Client new version 8.1 how to request a search

Tags: api, elasticsearch

Just struggelin with the new Elastic version 8.1 cause have no idea how to migrate a simple serch into the new api:

The old approach:

```
...    
final BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "Paul"));

final SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("/myIndex");
searchRequest.searchType(SearchType.DEFAULT).source(searchSourceBuilder);
final SearchResponse sr = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
...
```

This was straight forward. Could find out the hits etc. from the response and everything worked fine.

But with the new approach i cannot handle the searchrequest as it was before:

```
final SearchResponse<TDocument> sr1 = client.search(searchRequest, Class<TDocument> tDocumentClass);
```

For what is the TDocument type needed and how to define my model that it will fit into the API?

Comment: were you able to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going deeper into some tutorials i finally find a solution for a simple problem. See:

```
    final Query query = new Query.Builder().term(t -> t.field("field_looking_for").value(v -> v.stringValue("value_looking_for"))).build();
    final Query bool_query = new Query.Builder().bool(t -> t.must(query)).build();

    try {
        final SearchResponse<ChannelDto> result = client.search(s -> s.query(bool_query).index(INDEX).size(100), Dto.class);
        if (!result.hits().hits().isEmpty()) {
            for (final Hit<Dto> data_result : result.hits().hits()) {
                Dto dto = data_result.source();
                return dto;
            }
        }
    } catch (ElasticsearchException | IOException e) {
        throw new NoDataException("IO Exception", e);
    }
```